# jsPDF addSvgAsImage, canvg is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, canvg

I'm using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) in my Typescript React project and I want to as an SVG to my PDF using jsPDF.

I use [`addSvgAsImage`](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html#~addSvgAsImage) like this:

```js
let svg = this.ref.innerHTML
if (svg)
  svg = svg.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').trim()

pdf.addSvgAsImage(svg, 15, 45, 270, 130, 'SLOW')
```

and in my browser I got this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: canvg is not defined
    at Object.et.addSvgAsImage (jspdf.min.js?e511:180)
    ...
```

It seems that I should include `canvg` globally (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2205), but I have no clue how I can do that.

Does anyone tried `addSvgAsImage` in a React project or has an idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find the solution for a **React 16.10.2** project using **Webpack 4** and it's quite simple:

**`webpack.config.js`:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      canvg: 'canvg',
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

**`MyComponent.js`:**

```
// ...
  const svg = useRef(null)
  // ...

  if (svg.current) {
    const svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg.current)
    pdf.addSvgAsImage(svgData, 0, 0, 270, 130)
    pdf.save('a4.pdf')
    }
// ...
```

however, the quality of the SVG is not good, therefor I started using [**html2canvas**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas).

Comment: I can't find webpack.config.js.